# c# Переименовать файл по шаблону

Tags: c#

Как переименовать файл по шаблону. Так как каждый раз точное название разное но начало одинаковое.

В папке всегда лежит 1 файл с названием **Отчет по товарам_ср, 2 февр. 2022 г., 15_39_51 GMT+5.xlsx**

Его необходимо переименовать на **Отчет.xlsx** чтобы мне было потом легко к нему обратиться и вызвать.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.IO;

// найти файл
var file = Directory.GetFiles("путь к папке", "Отчет по товарам*.xlsx").Single();
// переименовать
File.Move(file.FullName, Path.Combine(file.Directory.FullName, "Отчет.xlsx"));
```